# NuGet restore overwiting signed DLLs

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

The entry point assembly for our application is signed with a strong-name key, so .NET requires all referenced assemblies to be signed as well. For those packages that publish unsigned assemblies our workaround was to sign them manually using ildasm/ilasm with the process explained [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewCE64BEF3-51A6-4F1C-90C9-6A76B015C9FB.htm), and checked in the strong-named assembly to git repository.

On the build machine we did `git pull` to get signed DLLs and then `.nuget\NuGet.exe restore App.sln` to restore the rest of packages. NuGet restore did not overwrite the signed/checked-in assembly files under *packages* folder, so we could build the solution fine.

Only recently I noticed that this is not working anymore and only for one of the signed DLLs `nuget restore` overwrites it with the original unsigned assembly that comes with the package. I cannot figure why this is working differently now and why it's happening for only one of the packages.

- How does `NuGet restore` decide when to overwrite an existing DLL for a package and when to skip it?
- Is there any better way to address this strong naming requirement when using unsigned packages?

NuGet.exe version is 3.4.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the latest [NuGet source](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client) it looks to me as though there is an initial check for any missing .nupkg files in the packages directory, I am assuming that you are not using a project.json file, and then it tries to restore only those NuGet packages where it cannot find an .nupkg file. However this is just me reading the code and ideally I would need to debug it to see what if that is how it really works.

To workaround this you could take a look at using the [StrongNamer NuGet package](https://github.com/dsplaisted/strongnamer) which will strongly name all assemblies at build time so the restore will no longer be a problem.

Comment: Including the `.nupkg` file fixed it. Thanks!